# Remove rows in database by Dataset with relationship in SQLite

Tags: c#, linq-to-dataset, dataset-designer

i have simple database and dataset, which looks like:
file:
*myDb*

```
klasa = class room
nauczyciel = teacher
```

[image]

`klasa data`:
[image]

`teacher data`:

[image]

now i want to remove teacher, which has ID equals 2:
it's whole code:

```
        DataSet2 db = new DataSet2();
        nauczycielTableAdapter teacherAdapter = new nauczycielTableAdapter();
        teacherAdapter.Fill(db.nauczyciel);

        klasaTableAdapter classAdapter = new klasaTableAdapter();
        classAdapter.Fill(db.klasa);

        var teacherToRemove = db.nauczyciel.Where(p => p.nauczycielID == 2).SingleOrDefault();

        DataRow[] classesTeacher = teacherToRemove.GetChildRows(db.Relations["FK_klasa_0_0"]);
        if (classesTeacher.Length == 0)
        {
            teacherToRemove.Delete();
            teacherAdapter.Update(db.nauczyciel);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("You must first remove classes teacher");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

**FK_klasa_0_0** - it's name of relationship between `klasa` and `nauczyciel`

I get a exception:

*Additional information: Concurrency Violation: the Delete Command element relates to the following number of records: 0 (expected number of records: 1).*

How could i remove this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it resolve my problem:
i created same database but names it with extension .sqlite. The previous database not had this extension and it may make me problems.